# API restSharp JSON payload remove Parameter

Tags: json, api, restsharp, payload

I am trying to create a 400 bad request, by removing an existing parameter from the payload in my step definitions. So, far i have tried various scenarios but not been successful in removing a parameter from the payload object. The payload object has been created a in separate class, at run time i just want to remove a single parameter (paymentAmount). How do i do this?

```
    [Given(@"the person has not sent the payment amount")]
    public void GivenTheValuerHasNotSentThePaymentAmount()
    {
       
        var requestHandler = scenarioContext.Get<RestRequestHandler>("requestHandler");
        
        var invalidPaymentRequest = StatusRequest.PaymentStatus();
        
        requestHandler.APIEndPoint = string.Format(requestHandler.APIEndPoint, paymentnumber);

        requestHandler.Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invalidPaymentRequest);

        var response = requestHandler.MakeAPICall();
        scenarioContext.Add("response", response);
    }
```